# Problem with function which create and return pointer to dynamic vector

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, pointers, vector

I have to crate a function which gets a reference to int array as one of arguments. This function should creates a dynamic vector and returns its pointer.
When I compile this code I got err: "No matching function for call to 'func'".
I have no idea what's wrong.
Immediately, I would like to ask if I removed the dynamic vector from the memory correctly or should I write it differently?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> *func(int &, int);
int main() {
  const int arrSize = 5;
  int arr[arrSize] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
  vector<int> *ptr_vec = func(arr, arrSize);
  delete ptr_vec;
}
vector<int> *func(int &arr, int size){
  auto *newVec = new vector<int>;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) newVec[i].push_back(arr+i);
  return newVec;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't return a `vector*`. Just return a `vector` and let the move constructor take care of things.

Comment: *This function should creates a dynamic vector and returns its pointer.* --  Totally unnecessary.  Return the `vector` itself.  Also, `vector` has a constructor where you don't need to do any of what you're doing now:  `std::vector<int> vec(arr, arr + arrSize);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the function is a reference to a scalar object of the type int

```
vector<int> *func(int &, int);
```

You need to write

```
vector<int> *func( const int *, int);
```

Also in the for loop you have to write

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) newVec->push_back(arr[i]);
```

In fact the for loop is redundant. Your function could look simpler as for example

```
vector<int> * func( const int *arr, int size )
{
    return new std::vector<int> { arr, arr + size };
}
```

Pay attention to that there is no great sense to define the vector dynamically. The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
vector<int> func( const int *arr, int size )
{
  return { arr, arr + size };
}
```

Comment: Yea, I know it doesn't make sense, but I got this assignment from university

Comment: `return { arr, arr + size };` I think this wants to give you a vector with 2 items.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Do you think or did you think?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ha, didn't know that works.

Comment: @SQTX *but I got this assignment from university* -- Whoever is teaching you C++ is doing a disservice and/or the teacher(s) are Java or similar programmers who do not know C++ well enough.  It looks like they're using Java, etc. as models in teaching (and writing) C++ programming and code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, exactly it is. He tell us that he mainly writes in Java, if I remember well.